# Show that the variance of the market portfolio is the weighted average of the ovariances between each constituent and the market portfolio itself

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, probability, statistical-finance

Let us assume that the market portfolio consists of n assets.
Given that the return of the market portfolio can be written as $r_m = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j$, we have that $\sigma^2_m = E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j - E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j))^2$, but how do I show that $$E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j - E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j))^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jCov(r_j,r_m)$$?
If I show that the equation above is true, than I can claim that $$E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j - E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j))^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jCov(r_j,r_m) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_j\beta\sigma^2_m$$

This is how I am trying to prove the result.
We know that:

$$\sigma^2_m = E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j - E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j))^2= E[(w_jr_j)^2]-E^2[w_jr_j]$$

Accordingly, we may show that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jCov(r_j,r_m) = E[(w_jr_j)^2]-E^2[w_jr_j]$$

Now:
$\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jCov(r_j,r_m) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jE[r_jr_m]-\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jE[r_j]E[r_m]=\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jE[r_j\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j]-\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jE[r_j]E[\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j]=\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jE[\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j^2]-E[\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j]E[\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j]$

It looks like I am not able to prove the result because 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jE[\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_jr_j^2] \neq E[(w_jr_j)^2]$$

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

The variance of the portfolio is $$ V_p=\sum_i \sum_j w_i w_j Cov(r_i,r_j)$$

because of the properties of $Cov(\cdot,\cdot)$ (namely that Covariance is linear with respect to the second argument: $Cov(x,\alpha y+\beta y)=\alpha Cov(x,y)+\beta Cov(x,z)$ we can rewrite this as $$ V_p=\sum_i w_i Cov(r_i,\underbrace{\sum_j w_j r_j}_{R_P})$$ where $R_p$ is the return on the portfolio. So we have

$$ V_p=\sum_i w_i Cov(r_i,R_p)$$ QED

(And it is true of every portfolio, not just the market portfolio).

Comment: Thank you. Could I ask you what was wrong with my previous sketch proof, please?

Answer (score 1):

$$
V[r_m] = Cov(r_m, r_m) = Cov(\sum w_j r_j, r_m) = 
\sum_j w_j Cov(r_j, r_m).
$$
You need the linearity of cov:
$$
\begin{align}
C[aX + bY, Z]  &= E[(aX + bY - am_X - bm_Y)(Z-m_Z)]\\
&= E[(aX - am_X)(Z-m_Z)] + E[(bY - bm_Y)(Z-m_Z)]\\
&= aC(X, Z) + bC(Y,Z).
\end{align}
$$